# What's the purpose of своё in this sentence?

Tags: словоупотребление, падежи, одним-словом, прилагательные

Here's a sentence from my book: Покрытые злобными колючками ежевичные плети изгибались над отжившими своё зарослями папоротника.

Why is своё in this sentence and why does it have this specific declension? To the best of my knowledge, there isn't even another word here that matches its case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The word «время» is omitted, but implied: «отжить свое время» = «to live past one's time». So in this case, it means that the fern (папоротник) is very old or maybe even dead.

The phrase «отжить свое» is commonly used to indicate both physical old age and death, as well as to indicate that something is outdated or archaic.

Comment: I don't really think there's an implied word (_время_ or otherwise), it's just "outlive what's theirs".

Comment: @Quassnoi I still think there is; at least, ruscorpora gives 15 instances of "отжил своё", of which 5 are "отжил свое время", while the remaining 10 have no noun after "свое". So, "отжил свое время" is quite popular, while "отжил свое <что-то еще>" is not used at all.

Comment: ...well, one example is "отжил свое величие", but this sounds strange to me anyway.

Comment: I just can't think of this ellipsis happening in anything other than singular neuter. There are expressions like _получил своё, это не моё_ and numerous others, and if you think hard enough you can come up with an "ellipsed" word to retrofit into them, but _*получил свой_ or _*это не моя_ is just not how it works, it's always singular neuter.

Comment: @Quassnoi good point

Answer (score 13):

> Why is *своё* in this sentence and why does it have this specific declension?

*Отжить своё* is a set expression literally meaning "to outlive one's own (allotted time)".

It's not a case of ellipsis. The word for "time" in Russian is *время* which is neuter, but that's mere coincidence.

In Russian, the substantivization of adjectives (or verbs through deverbal adjectives) is performed by putting them into the singular neuter: *мороженое* "ice cream" (literally, "that which is frozen"); *заливное* "aspic" (literally, "that which is poured over"); *спиртное* "booze" (literally, "that which is related to alcohol") etc.

Even though these words do look like singular neuter adjectives, they are in fact nouns in their own right and don't modify anything in the sentence.

Other set expressions with possessive pronouns in this substantivized sense are *каждому своё* "to each his own", *получить своё* "to get what's due", *это не моё* "this is not my cup of tea" and many others.

---

As a side note, it's interesting to note that in Church Slavonic, this was achieved by putting words into the plural neuter. Hence the words: *преисподняя* "hell" ("that which is the most nether"), *вселенная* "universe" ("that which has been populated"), *прочая, прочая, прочая* "and so on and so forth" ("that which is other, other, other") etc. These words are etymologically Church Slavonic adjectives in the plural neuter, but in modern Russian, they've re-emerged as singular feminine nouns.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, своё не имеет отношение к только ко времени. Есть выражения - отдать своё. Своё можно перевести как - own или what it had, what it might, that it will. Где it имеет отношение к внутренней силе - willpower, own standing, own being, ownself.

Своё, самоё(самоё себя) - это специфические местоимения, обозначающее внутреннюю сущность и внутреннее долженствование, что-то близкое к юнговскому подсознанию, фрейдовскому бессознательному или может к essence вещи, короче к ОНО -  и отношению ОНО к бытию вообще, потому и ко времени и к имуществу, к характеру и тд., что-то более общее связанное с владением, волей и самостью.

Отжившие своё заросли - это умершие сами по себе от старости, а не от непогоды или иного рода внешнего воздействия. То что жило, было красиво, юно, боролось, развивалось, но теперь мертво окончательно, однако сожалеть об этом нет смысла, потому что ничто не вечно и это закон бытия. Смерть как факт без сожаления. И эта фраза на противопоставлении эмоционального пассажа: Покрытые(mystery) злобными(emotion) колючками(danger) ежевичные(berries-life-sweets) плети(something between lash and bonds for slaves ~ depression) изгибались(flexing) над(domini). То есть жизнь - страсти и страдание, а смерть - покой в качестве награды за страдания.

Ps.: Еще я обнаружил, что данная фраза, это перевод произведения английского писателя Chris Priestley’s Uncle Montagu’s Tale of Terror и перевод весьма литературный, интересно прочитать эту фразу в оригинале, а то я тут напереводил обратно, интересно насколько это соответствует тому что предполагал автор. Так что если кто-то может добавить эту строчку на оригинале, буду признателен.

> Снежный шар
>
> Некоторое время спустя я снова оказался на извилистой лесной тропинке, ведущей к дому дядюшки Монтегю.
>
> Дело было зимой. Деревья стояли мертвенно-нагие, темная, сырая земля под ними полнилась таинственными шорохами. Покрытые злобными колючками ежевичные плети изгибались над отжившими свое зарослями папоротника.

Comment: "Viciously spiked brambles arched and coiled among the dead bracken"

Comment: Thank you! The translator created his own narrative i think.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no need to reinvent the wheel because when you have an idiom, the best thing is to look it up in a dictionary of idioms that will tell us firstly that it's an idiom, which means that we should consider two words as a whole. Своё can have different meanings in other collocations, be mindful of that! Grammatically, it's a substantivized possessive pronoun, and in this idiom it doesn't change.

On the whole, отжить свое is a colloquial variation of отжить свое время and время means *life*.(So it refers to the end of one's life).
Note the following dictionary entry:

Отжить своё
ОТЖИВАТЬ СВОЁ. ОТЖИТЬ СВОЁ. Разг. То же, что Отживать своё время (в 1-м знач.). Вы, батя, своё уже отжили, так и нечего вам становиться на нашу дорогу (С. Бабаевский. Кавалер Золотой Звезды).

Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка. — М.: Астрель, АСТ. А. И. Фёдоров. 2008.